# Click event is not working when <tr> added dynamically using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Click event of jQuery is not working. In ajax I am adding a table row dynamically which contains a button with the class `btn btn-default getEditCategory`. It is not working.

**This is my ajax success function to add a table row dynamically**

```
var addCatUrl = $("#addCategories").attr('action');

success: function(data) {
    if(data) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        if(data.status === true) {
            var ajxMsg = data.message;
            var categoryList = data.data;
            var html = " ";
            var sr = 0;
            $.each(categoryList, function(key, category) {
                sr++;
                if(category.status == 1) { 
                    var statusHtml = "<span class='label label-success catActive'>Active</span>";
                } else {
                    var statusHtml = "<span class='label label-danger catInActive'>InActive</span>";
                }

                html += "<tr><td>"+sr+"</td><td>"+category.name+"</td><td>"+statusHtml+"</td><td>"+category.creationDate+"</td><td><span><button class='btn btn-default getEditCategory' id='getEditCategory' data-id='"+category.id+"' type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editCategoryModal'><i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></span><span><button class='btn btn-default deleteCategory' id='deleteCategory' data-id='"+category.id+"' type='button'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></span></td></tr>";
            });
            $("#categoryList").append(html);
        }   
    }
}
```

**This is my click event which is not working**

```
$("button.btn btn-default deleteCategory").click(function(){
    alert("Delete coming soon..");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#categoryList').on('click', 'button.deleteCategory', function(){
   alert("Delete coming soon..");
});
```

Here, we are binding a `click` event on `#categoryList` element and filtering out only events on `button.deleteCategory` elements. This way, it does not matter if you bound your event on existing `tr` or newly created.

Answer (score 1):

The events are bound at DOM initiation , but your element will not be present. You can use following code to do that.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', "button.deleteCategory",
    function () {
       alert("Delete coming soon..");
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I havent seen the code that handles the event you are talking about, but If you haven't used event delegation, use it or if you don't know it at all make some research

Instead of

```js
$('.my-table-row').click(function(){
  ///some code here
  
  
  });
```

do something like

```js
$('#my-table').on('click','.my-table-row', function(){
  //Some code here
  
  
  });
```

you can replace #my-table with any static element like document itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamic element. Also your selector is wrong. Try like following.

```
$("#categoryList").on('click', '.deleteCategory', function () {
    alert("Delete coming soon..");
});
```

N.B: You are duplicating the id `getEditCategory` and `deleteCategory`. You don't need to use these ids as there are classes as well.